# jQuery Validate using onclick handler not validating fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to use an onlick event handler to validate some form fields using jquery Validate. To do this I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name">  
<a class="btn btn-primary js-add-names" href="#">Add Names</a> 

<input type="text" id="Age" name="Age">
<a class="btn btn-primary js-add-ages" href="#">Add Age</a> 

<script>


   $(".js-add-names").click(function (e) {

     e.preventDefault();

     $("form").validate({
        rules: {
          Name: {
             required: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          Name: "The Name is required"
        }

     });

     if (!$("form").valid()) {
        return;
     }

     //  otherwise do stuff but we dont want to submit form
   });


   $(".js-add-ages").click(function (e) {

     e.preventDefault();

     $("form").validate({
        rules: {
          Age: {
             required: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          Age: "The Age is required"
        }

     });

     if (!$("form").valid()) {
        return;
     }

     //  otherwise do stuff but we dont want to submit form
   });

</script>
```

What I've noticed is that only one event handler works out the two based on whichever one was clicked first i.e. if I click the button with class js-add-names, the validation for that handler works as expected.

Now If I click the button with class js-add-ages having previously clicked js-add-names then the handler for js-add-age doesn't work and vis versa?

Any ideas why this is happening and what is the fix?

---

*** UPDATE ***

Further to suggestion by Sparky I have re-written the code as below but now when I  click js-add-names, the validation for that handler works as expected

Now If I click the button with class js-add-ages having previously clicked js-add-names then the handler for js-add-age doesn't work becuase the validation has previously added a rule for input #Name. How do I reset the form or remove the rules each time the event handlers fire?

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name">  
   <a class="btn btn-primary js-add-names" href="#">Add Names</a> 

   <input type="text" id="Age" name="Age">
   <a class="btn btn-primary js-add-ages" href="#">Add Age</a> 

   // other inputs
   <input type="checkbox" name="CarOwner" value="Yes"> Car owner

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>

   $("form").validate();

   $(".js-add-names").click(function (e) {

     e.preventDefault();

     $("#Age").rules("remove");

     $("#Name").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "The Name is required"
        }
     });

     if (!$("form").valid()) {
        return;
     }

     //  otherwise do stuff but we dont want to submit form
     //  ...

     //Reset input field
     $("#Name").val('');
   });


   $(".js-add-ages").click(function (e) {

     e.preventDefault();

     $("#Name").rules("remove");

     $("#Age").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "The Age is required"
        }
     });

     if (!$("form").valid()) {
        return;
     }

     //  otherwise do stuff but we dont want to submit form
     //  ...

     //Reset input field
     $("#Age").val('');
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to validate one field by click or might validate 2 fields at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas why this is happening and what is the fix?

The `.validate()` method is only used for initializing the plugin on your form and therefore should only be called **once** when the page is loaded.  Subsequent calls are always ignored.  So when you use one `click` handler, you initialize the validate plugin, and the other call to `.validate()` in the other `click` handler will do nothing.

The fix...

1. Call `.validate()` ONE time to initialize the plugin on your form.
2. Do NOT call `.validate()` from a `click` handler since this is not the testing method; it's only the initialization method.
3. Use the plugin's built-in `submitHandler` and `invalidHandler` functions for stuff you need to do when the form is valid and invalid.
4. Since you appear to be using your `click` handlers to add fields/rules to an existing form, then use [the `.rules('add')` and `.rules('remove')` methods](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to add and remove any rules dynamically.

Comment: Quote @adam78 : *"How do I reset the form or remove the rules each time the event handlers fire?"*  ~ See my edits... use a `.rules('remove')`.

Comment: I've added the .rules('remove') but now I've noticed the form is requiring a double click on all my form inputs and buttons?

Comment: @adam78, I am absolutely not seeing any behavior like that here... everything is working as expected without double-clicks:  http://jsfiddle.net/yvop9t91/